# Error while deploy my project nextjs in vercel

Tags: node.js, npm, next.js, vercel

I'm trying to deploy my project on vercel. When I

```
npm run build
```

and

```
npm run start
```

on my machine, it's fine. But when in the vercel log it gets an error like:

```
144 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
Detected Next.js version: 14.1.3
Detected `package-lock.json` generated by npm 7+
Running "npm run build"
> aeroxee-blog@0.1.0 build
> next build
Attention: Next.js now collects completely anonymous telemetry regarding usage.
This information is used to shape Next.js' roadmap and prioritize features.
You can learn more, including how to opt-out if you'd not like to participate in this anonymous program, by visiting the following URL:
https://nextjs.org/telemetry
   ▲ Next.js 14.1.3
   Creating an optimized production build ...
free(): invalid size
Error: Command "npm run build" exited with SIGABRT
```

This is my node version in my machine.
node: v20.2.3
npm: v10.2.3

I want to deploy my nextjs project to vercel.